# Find the index of the sublist that has the error?

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists, and I want to find the index of the sublist whose length is not 4. This is what the list looks like:

```
l = [['"a"','"b"','"c"','"d"'],['"a"','"b"','"c"','"d"'],['"a"','"b"','"c"','"d"','"e"']
```

The third sublist does not have an length of 4, so I would have to report back to the user that the third row does not have the correct length.

This is my code:

```
x = max(len(l) for i in l)
        if x == 4:
            return True
        elif x != 4:
            for i in l:
               c = l.index(i)
            print(c)      #returns 4...
```

EDIT: The first sublist is actually a header, so just the index of the sublist with the error should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use `next()` and `enumerate()`:

```
index = next(i for i, sublist in enumerate(l) if len(l) != 4)
```

This will raise `StopIteration` if there is all sublists are length 4 or there are no sublists. You can ask `next()` to return a default value instead:

```
index = next((i for i, sublist in enumerate(l) if len(l) != 4), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
>>> [len(v) == 4 for v in l].index(False)
2
```

Comment: This loops twice; once to generate the list, a second time to scan the resulting list for the index.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I doubt this will be the source of a performance issue. I find it to be the most intuitive, understandable, and easy-to-write approach.

Comment: I am just making clear what the drawbacks are of using this approach. If `l` is large and the first list not of length 4 is towards the end, you have both a memory and CPU issue here.